# Installation of Kivy in Python 3.8.2 is occuring Error

Tags: python, kivy

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO YOGA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78_a5546\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO YOGA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78_a5546\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-t3zgxbq2'
         cwd: C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78_a5546\kivy\
    Complete output (388 lines):
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO YOGA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4uht95r0\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO YOGA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4uht95r0\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-o7vvpx89'
           cwd: C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4uht95r0\cython\
      Complete output (321 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      copying cython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Includes\openmp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\array.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bool.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytearray.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ceval.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\datetime.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\dict.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\function.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\instance.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\int.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\long.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\longintrepr.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\method.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\module.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\number.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\object.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pylifecycle.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pystate.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bool.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_complex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_dict.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_exc.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_float.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_function.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_instance.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_int.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_long.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_method.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_module.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_number.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_object.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_ref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_set.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_type.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_version.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\forward_list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\functional.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\map.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\pair.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\queue.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\set.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\stack.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeindex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\typeinfo.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_map.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\unordered_set.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\utility.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\vector.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\math.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\dlfcn.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\fcntl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\ioctl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\mman.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\resource.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\select.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stat.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\strings.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\time.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\types.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\unistd.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\wait.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Runtime
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\codefile -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\cfuncs.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Plex\Actions.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Utility\CConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CpdefEnums.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCythonScope.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCyUtilityLoader.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\AsyncGen.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Buffer.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Builtins.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Capsule.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CMath.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CommonStructures.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Complex.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Coroutine.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CythonFunction.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Embed.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Exceptions.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ExtensionTypes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\FunctionArguments.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ImportExport.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView_C.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ModuleSetupCode.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ObjectHandling.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Optimize.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Overflow.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Printing.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Profile.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      running build_ext
      building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\LENOVO YOGA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp903ly__7', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78_a5546\kivy\setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
       File "C:\Users\LENOVO YOGA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\LENOVO YOGA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp903ly__7', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 3221225595)

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 3221225595)

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 3221225595)

    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Here, Problem is after installing Kivy through this kivy Is not installed it just shows that your requirements are fullfilled by that command but it still won't Install Kivy... it's fulfilling  temporary Requirement at the time of call of command.

If you use command "`kivy --version`" you can check kivy is installed or not.

---

so tell me how to install kivy fully.

Answer (score 0):

According to error, you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual
```

After installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, run the below command:

```
pip install -U steem
```

Run this command if above command doesn't work

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

*OR*

```
pip wheel setuptools
```

Comment: @Parzival can you try this and let me know whether it's working or not?